# How to extract GPU information in electron app?

Tags: javascript, gpu, electron

Is there an option to retrieve what graphic card is running on the system (Windows) that does not require usage of chrome://gpu/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a quick google search, I found a package called `systeminfo` and it has a function called `graphics`. It will return an array of graphics controllers and displays which you can filter by the two major vendors (ATI/AMD and nVidia).

Package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/systeminformation